# How to assign a single element in a multidimensional array (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

I don't know why I'm seeing the below:

```
const sideLength = 4;
const multiArray = new Array(sideLength).fill(new Array(sideLength));
console.log(multiArray)
var counter = 1;
multiArray[3][1] = counter;
console.log('multiArray:', multiArray)
```

Console output:

```
[ [ , , ,  ], [ , , ,  ], [ , , ,  ], [ , , ,  ] ]
multiArray: [ [ , 1, ,  ], [ , 1, ,  ], [ , 1, ,  ], [ , 1, ,  ] ]
```

I would have expected the second line of output to be:

```
multiArray: [ [ , , ,  ], [ , , ,  ], [ , , ,  ], [ , 1, ,  ] ]
```

Why is that `1` being added to every array's index=1 element?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The fill() method fills all the elements of an array from a start index to an end index with a static value.

That means all elements would refer to the same array. Changing the value of of one element would change the value of all elements since they refer to the same static object

Comment: thanks for your explanation, @marvel308. could you please help me to understand why the first console.log(multiArray) in the example above also log updated array value out

Comment: thanks @marvel308. there must be something wrong with console dev tool :). https://image.prntscr.com/image/a6vTGz-CQWq40RFl8pbfdQ.jpg

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Array.from()` to create an `Array` having a specific `.length`

```js
const sideLength = 4;
const multiArray = Array.from({length:sideLength}, () => new Array(sideLength));
console.log(multiArray)
var counter = 1;
multiArray[3][1] = counter;
console.log('multiArray:', multiArray)
```